# Dynamic Time Warping in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parallel-processing

I translated a DTW matlab function to Swift. The code looks as follows:

```
private func dtw(x1 : [Double], x2 : [Double]) -> Double {
    let n1 = x1.count;
    let n2 = x2.count;
    var table =  [[Double]](repeating: [Double](repeating: 0, count: n2 + 1), count: 2);
    table[0][0] = 0;
    for i in 1...n2 { table[0][i] = Double.infinity }
    
    for i in 1 ... n1 {
        table[1][0] = Double.infinity;
        for j in 1 ... n2 {
            let cost = abs(x1[i - 1] - x2[j - 1]);
            var min = table[0][j - 1];
            if (min > table[0][j]) {
                min = table[0][j];
            }
            if (min > table[1][j - 1]) { min = table[1][j - 1]; }
            
            table[1][j] = cost + min;
        }
        let swap = table[0];
        table[0] = table[1];
        table[1] = swap;
    }
    return table[0][n2];
}
```

This function takes an average of 16 ms to complete on an iPhone 11. For my use case, this is very slow. I want to investigate ways to improve speed. I recently read these two articles : [DTW in Swift Orailly](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/machine-learning-with/9781787121515/145416fd-5499-4377-9466-cf16b53093d8.xhtml) and [Parallel programming with Swift](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/basics-of-parallel-programming-with-swift-93fee8425287). In the first article, there is a good quote:

> Our implementation of DTW is naïve, and can be accelerated using parallel computing. To calculate the new row/column in a distance matrix, you don't need to wait until the previous one is finished; you only need it to be filled one cell ahead of your row/column

This would make the for j in 1 ... n2 { for loop an ideal candidate. ( I think ) Looking at the code, only these two operations should be thread-safe due to the read / write:

```
table[1][j - 1]

table[1][j]
```

The problem I am currently experiencing in introducing parallel computing ( from article 2 ) is that I cannot figure out how to tell swift run everything in parallel, except when I come to the two below lines, as they depend on their predocessor:

```
if (min > table[1][j - 1]) { min = table[1][j - 1]; }
table[1][j] = cost + min;
```

I suspect I could solve this issue with [DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform) and an NSLock(), if I implemented it correctly. ( I have not ) It could also be the wrong tool of choice, yielding me back to my question:

What can I do, to improve the speed of my DTW function where the only constraint in performing a task is that the previous execution in an array had to have completed ( parallelization, concurrency, etc. ) A code example would go a long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're creating an array of arrays. This is not an efficient data structure, and is not a "2 dimensional array" in the way most people mean (i.e a matrix). It is an array made up of other arrays, all of which can have arbitrary sizes, and this can be very expensive to mutate. As a rule, if you want a matrix, you should back it with a flat array and use multiplication to find its offsets, particularly if you're mutating it. Instead of `table[i][j]` you would use `table[i * width + j]`.

But in your case it's even easier, since there are exactly two rows. So you don't a multi-dimensional array at all. You can just use two variables, and it'll be much more efficient. (In my tests, just making this change is about 30% faster than the original code.)

The major thing that slows you down is contention. You read and write to the same array in the loop. That gets in the way of various reordering and caching optimizations. In particular, it happens here:

```
        if (min > table[1][j - 1]) { min = table[1][j - 1]; }
        table[1][j] = cost + min;
```

If you rewrite that using two row variables rather than an array, it still looks like this:

```
        if (min > row1[j - 1]) { min = row1[j - 1] }
        row1[j] = cost + min
```

This forces the previous write to `row1` to be fully completed before the next minimum can be computed, and then requires an array lookup to get the value back. But that's not really necessary. You can just cache the previous value between loops. Doing that means the loop only performs reads on `row0` and only performs writes on `row1`. That's good for memory contention.

Putting those together, I wrote it this way. I changed the offsets to run from 0 rather than 1; it just made the code a little simpler to understand IMO. In my tests, this is about 3x faster than the original code for two arrays of 10k elements each.

```
func dtw(x1 : [Double], x2 : [Double]) -> Double {
    let n1 = x1.count
    let n2 = x2.count

    var row0 = Array(repeating: Double.infinity, count: n2 + 1)
    row0[0] = 0

    var row1 = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: n2 + 1)

    for i in 0 ..< n1 {
        row1[0] = .infinity

        // Keep track of the last value so we never have to read from row1.
        var lastValue = Double.infinity
        
        for j in 0 ..< n2 {
            let cost = abs(x1[i] - x2[j])

            // Don't be tempted to use the 3-value version of `min` here. It's much slower.
            var minimum = min(row0[j], row0[j + 1])
            minimum = min(minimum, lastValue)

            lastValue = cost + minimum
            row1[j + 1] = lastValue
        }

        swap(&row0, &row1)
    }
    return row0[n2];
}
```

This code is somewhat hard to make parallel, because the operations are not independent. Each row depends on the other rows. The key to good queue-based parallelism is the ability to split up fairly large chunks of independent work, and then efficiently combine them at the end. The cost of coordination will eat your benefits if the work units are too small. In many cases, vectorization (SIMD) is much more efficient than dispatching to multiple queues.

The `cost` function is independent, and I explored computing it with Accelerate (the main vectorization framework), but this generally made things slower. The compiler is very good at optimizing simple math in loops, and will do quite a lot of vectorizing for you if you let it. Accelerate is best when you need to do an expensive, consistent, and independent computation on a lot of values. And this loop isn't expensive or independent.

Comment: Rob, this is fantastic.